# libgit2sharp Fetch Failing

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am using libgit2sharp to on a proof of concept to automate fetching, changing, commiting some files, and pushing to a remote origin.

I know that **push** is still not finished yet, but **fetch** is in vnext but when I call it:

> An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Os (Error).
>   Failed to connect to host

Here is my code:

```
        using (var repo = new Repository(gitPath))
        {
            var allBranches = repo.Branches.ToList(); //works fine

            var creds = new Credentials() {Username = username, Password = password};
            var remote = repo.Remotes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "origin");
            remote.Fetch(credentials:creds);  //blows up here     


        }
```

Some other details:

1. My remote is private bitbucket hosted using https. (looks like: https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myRepoOwner/repoName.git)
2. I am able to fetch and push from the command line, so the repo is working.
3. The same issue happens when I use repo.Fetch("origin");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like [an issue that was recently fixed](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1298) in `libgit2` (and likely has not yet been integrated into `libgit2sharp`.)

In the mean time, you should be able to remove the `myusername@` from your remote URI to work around this problem, eg `https://bitbucket.org/myRepoOwner/repoName.git`.